# How to save Dask array to hdf5 when using distributed

Tags: python, dask, hdf5, dask-distributed

I start with a simple code to generate dask array and then save it to hdf5.

```py
import dask.array as da

darr = da.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100, 500), chunks=(10, 20), dtype="int16")
darr.to_hdf5("tmp.h5", "/x")
```

This works fine when I use dask locally just as a library. The problem arises when I run the same code using distributed scheduler

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client(set_as_default=True)
```

In that case execution of `darr.to_hdf5()` throws an error. This is surprising to me as dumping result of computation run on cluster seems like basic feature. Am I missing something? How can I save results of my computations?

---

I use `Python 3.8.12`, `dask 2021.9.1`, `dask-core 2021.9.1`, `h5py 3.4.0` from `daskdev/dask-notebook` Docker container.
The error message:

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 285, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 57, in _encode_default
    sub_header, sub_frames = serialize_and_split(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 425, in serialize_and_split
    header, frames = serialize(x, serializers, on_error, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 252, in serialize
    return serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 298, in serialize
    headers_frames = [
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 349, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type Dataset.', '<HDF5 dataset "x": shape (100, 500), type "<i2">')
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type Dataset.', '<HDF5 dataset "x": shape (100, 500), type "<i2">')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 33, in _to_frames
    return list(protocol.dumps(msg, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 285, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 57, in _encode_default
    sub_header, sub_frames = serialize_and_split(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 425, in serialize_and_split
    header, frames = serialize(x, serializers, on_error, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 252, in serialize
    return serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 298, in serialize
    headers_frames = [
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 349, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type Dataset.', '<HDF5 dataset "x": shape (100, 500), type "<i2">')
distributed.batched - ERROR - Error in batched write
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/batched.py", line 93, in _background_send
    nbytes = yield self.comm.write(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 243, in write
    frames = await to_frames(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 50, in to_frames
    return _to_frames()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py", line 33, in _to_frames
    return list(protocol.dumps(msg, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 76, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 292, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 298, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 295, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 285, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 57, in _encode_default
    sub_header, sub_frames = serialize_and_split(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 425, in serialize_and_split
    header, frames = serialize(x, serializers, on_error, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 252, in serialize
    return serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 298, in serialize
    headers_frames = [
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 349, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type Dataset.', '<HDF5 dataset "x": shape (100, 500), type "<i2">')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_58/1886317945.py in <module>
      2 
      3 darr = da.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100, 500), chunks=(10, 20), dtype="int16")
----> 4 darr.to_hdf5("tmp.h5", "/x")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in to_hdf5(self, filename, datapath, **kwargs)
   1594         h5py.File.create_dataset
   1595         """
-> 1596         return to_hdf5(filename, datapath, self, **kwargs)
   1597 
   1598     def to_dask_dataframe(self, columns=None, index=None, meta=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in to_hdf5(filename, *args, **kwargs)
   4929             for dp, x in data.items()
   4930         ]
-> 4931         store(list(data.values()), dsets)
   4932 
   4933 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in store(sources, targets, lock, regions, compute, return_stored, **kwargs)
   1041     else:
   1042         if compute:
-> 1043             compute_as_if_collection(Array, store_dsk, store_keys, **kwargs)
   1044             return None
   1045         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute_as_if_collection(cls, dsk, keys, scheduler, get, **kwargs)
    313     schedule = get_scheduler(scheduler=scheduler, cls=cls, get=get)
    314     dsk2 = optimization_function(cls)(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
--> 315     return schedule(dsk2, keys, **kwargs)
    316 
    317 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in get(self, dsk, keys, workers, allow_other_workers, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   2687                     should_rejoin = False
   2688             try:
-> 2689                 results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
   2690             finally:
   2691                 for f in futures.values():

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in gather(self, futures, errors, direct, asynchronous)
   1964             else:
   1965                 local_worker = None
-> 1966             return self.sync(
   1967                 self._gather,
   1968                 futures,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    858             return future
    859         else:
--> 860             return sync(
    861                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    862             )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    324     if error[0]:
    325         typ, exc, tb = error[0]
--> 326         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    327     else:
    328         return result[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    307             if callback_timeout is not None:
    308                 future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
--> 309             result[0] = yield future
    310         except Exception:
    311             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    760 
    761                     try:
--> 762                         value = future.result()
    763                     except Exception:
    764                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   1830                         else:
   1831                             raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
-> 1832                         raise exc
   1833                     if errors == "skip":
   1834                         bad_keys.add(key)

CancelledError: ('store-9017f62a-3721-11ec-8752-0242ac110002', 7, 2)
```

Comment: I can reproduce this; Including a link to your issue here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/927#issuecomment-952891526